# Sybase Authentication Issue When Updating Via SSIS

Tags: ado.net, ssis, sybase

In an SSIS package I am using an ADO.Net connection with a Sybase v9 data provider to make a series of updates.

The package will fail randomly with an error message of 'Authentication violation', it is never on the same record.
After a bit of research I have found out that Sybase requiers a connection_authentication string in the following format:

```
SET TEMPORARY OPTION connection_authentication='Company=CompanyName Plc;Application=AppName;Signature=000fa55157ed..etc'
```

I know the correct string for my database because I ran the following:

```
CALL sa_conn_properties( );
```

So I know the correct string to use but how do I incorporate it into SSIS. In theory it can be called as a SQL statement like so:

```
EXEC SQL SET TEMPORARY OPTION connection_authentication='Company=CompanyName Plc;Application=AppName;Signature=000fa55157ed..etc'
```

But when used in a SQL Task this just gives an error message 'connection_authentication cannot be set from within a procedure'. Ideally I would like to incorporate the string into the connection rather than change every SQL statement.

Comment: When you tried that from an Execute SQL Task, was the the only statement in there?

Comment: The idea I have by the way is to approach it in the same manner as I describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467641/how-do-i-set-the-sde-version-in-ssis-dataflow-source/14467776#14467776)

Comment: Had a chance to see if the single connection approach handles your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

In SSIS create a new ADO.Net connection manager.

For the provider select '.Net Providers\Odbc Data Provider'.

Select the radio button for Use connection string.

Enter a connection string in following format (but omitting the extra white space that I have added just for clarity):

```
Driver={Adaptive Server Anywhere 9.0};
uid=MyName;
compress=No;
commlinks=SharedMemory,TCPIP{Host=10.10.10.10};
disablemultirowfetch=Yes;
debug=No;
integrated=No;
autostop=No;
enginename=MyServer;
initstring=SET TEMPORARY OPTION CONNECTION_AUTHENTICATION='
    Company=MyComapny;
    application=MyApplication;
    signature=000fa552
```

The key part on the connection string is the initstring section where the authentication data is added.

I found the answer from the following page:

http://dcx.sybase.com/1201/en/dbadmin/running-s-3417964.html